# Can "nights" be an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, lyrics

Is "nights" an adverb in the second line of these song lyrics?

> I used to be a lunatic from the gracious days
> I used to feel woebegone and so restless **nights**
> My aching heart would bleed for you to see
> Oh, but now
> I don't find myself bouncing home
> Whistling buttonhole tunes to make me cry

From [No More "I Love You’s"](https://genius.com/Annie-lennox-no-more-i-love-yous-lyrics)

Comment: It isn’t. see the tour for how to ask good questions - yes/no questions aren’t good questions. Also don’t try to learn English grammar from song lyrics.

Comment: It is the form that are not used much this way now. In older days such use of nouns are called Genitive Adverbial, then over the time the genitive marking lost its presence but the "s" still held its ground.

Comment: @Man_From_India This is a normal plural noun. What makes you think it's a relic from a genitive adverbial?

Answer (score 1):

I would say a plural noun. I used to feel woebegone, and so [suffered from] restless nights.

Comment: Alternately, I used to feel woebegone and so [I was] restless nights. (i.e. a similar usage to "I used to work nights" or "I used to go there nights") (As an American outside the idiom of "working nights" I think this is a Britishism)

Comment: @ThePhoton - agreed. No-one has yet (including the OP) has yet seen fit to mention that the words quoted are the first verse of the 1986 song _No More 'I Love You's_ by the British musicians David Freeman and Joseph Hughes and originally recorded by them as the Lover Speaks. It was covered in 1995 by Annie Lennox (also British) on her second solo studio album. She had been half of Eurythmics from 1981 to 1990. The lyrics of the song in question are somewhat poetical and might be said to defy literal interpretation. Thus both our 'alternates' can be true.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I've also heard _How do you sleep nights?_ and seen (just now) _I don't want you to marry her because she goes out nights_.  I think of it as definitely American, and possibly kind of New York Yiddish influenced.

Comment: @ThePhoton - We say 'I work nights' in Britain, too, but e.g. 'sleeping nights' and 'going out nights' would be understood (naturally) but perceived as Americanisms.

Answer (score 1):

It's a plural noun. "Nights" is an alternative way of saying "at night". It's most common in "work nights" meaning to work at night.

The author means he feels webegone and restless at night.